# ASP WebReference namespace could not be found

Tags: asp.net, namespaces, web-reference

I've added a WebReference to my project - when I try to reference it, it says the namespace could not be found. I know the syntax is right, but I think there is something I need to do to include it in the project. Even though it's been added, it hasn't been "included" yet (at least that's what I've been told). I've tried many google searches, but I can't come up with anything as of yet. How would I do this? (assuming I'm on the right track)

Initializiation:

```
lmapiSoap.lmapi lm;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've simply renamed the Web Reference to be called lmapiSoap :D